# Deploying the .apk file generated in Jenkins to a mobile device

Tags: jenkins, apk, appium

I have a Jenkins job that creates a `.apk` file. I need to deploy this `.apk` file to a mobile device for running automation scripts.

I know we can use chained Jenkins jobs, but how do we pass the `.apk` file location?

Answer (score 0):

If the .apk path is static and Jenkins running on server machine, you can pass URL to install from that location.

```
driver.setCapability("app","<URL_of_APKFile>");
```

Please refer: https://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#appium-server-capabilities